# Adding color to results of PowerShell scripts Exception

Tags: xml, linq, powershell

I am fairly new to the Powershell world and having a bit of difficulty figuring this issue out. My code is below and pretty simple, compared to others I have done this with, but this one just will not work and I can't figure out what I have done wrong. I have done almost the exact same thing using much longer and more complex "Lists" to start from than the simple $VMToolsList I have below. When I run the code below I get the following error for both wsIndex1 and 2. Any idea of what I am missing?

*Exception calling "IndexOf" with "2" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: array"
At C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\f2dfef29-9e86-4193-9c37-98b35015e97f.ps1:9 char:2
+     $wsIndex1 = [Array]::IndexOf( $VMToolsxml.Descendants("${Namespace}th").Value,  ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException*

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq

New-VIProperty -Name ToolsVersion -ObjectType VirtualMachine -ValueFromExtensionProperty 'Config.tools.ToolsVersion' -Force 
New-VIProperty -Name ToolsVersionStatus -ObjectType VirtualMachine -ValueFromExtensionProperty 'Guest.ToolsVersionStatus' -Force
$VMToolsList = $(Get-VM | Select Name, Version, ToolsVersion, ToolsVersionStatus)

$VMToolsxml = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse( "$($VMToolsList | ConvertTo-Html)" )

$wsIndex1 = [Array]::IndexOf( $VMToolsxml.Descendants("${Namespace}th").Value, "Version")
$wsIndex2 = [Array]::IndexOf( $VMToolsxml.Descendants("${Namespace}th").Value, "ToolsVersionStatus")

foreach($row in $VMToolsxml.Descendants("${Namespace}tr")){
    switch(@($row.Descendants("${Namespace}td"))[$wsIndex1]) {
       {"v7" -eq $_.Value } { $_.SetAttributeValue( "style", "background: green;"); continue } 
       {"v7" -ne $_.Value } { $_.SetAttributeValue( "style", "background: red; font color: black"); continue } 
    }
    switch(@($row.Descendants("${Namespace}td"))[$wsIndex2]) {
       {"guestToolsCurrent" -eq $_.Value } { $_.SetAttributeValue( "style", "background: green;"); continue } 
       {"guestToolsNeedUpgrade" -eq $_.Value } { $_.SetAttributeValue( "style", "background: yellow; font color: black"); continue }
       {"guestToolsNotInstalled" -eq $_.Value } { $_.SetAttributeValue( "style", "background: red; font color: black"); continue }
       {"guestToolsUnmanaged" -eq $_.Value } { $_.SetAttributeValue( "style", "background: purple;"); continue }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should also add that I have this outputting to an email and the resulting report does come through properly with all the expected data populated, just without the colored formatting. And yes, I do have the vmware snap-in added and the connection to vcenter active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by debugging why `$VMToolsxml.Descendants("${Namespace}th").Value` is resulting in a null.  BTW XLinq and PowerShell don't work that great together. Descendants is an extension method which PowerShell does not automatically support. You would use the extension method this way:

```
[System.Xml.Linq.Extensions]::Descendants($VMToolsxml, "${Namespace}th")
```

I would consider using PowerShell's support of System.Xml.XmlDocument and use Select-Xml with an XPath query to find your nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Keith. Now that I have some fresh eyes after a good nights sleep I looked again at why it was returning null, as you suggested, and there it was. I neglected to define Namespace. Once I added in the code below, just after defining $VMToolsxml, it worked like a champ. 

'if($Namespace = $xml.Root.Attribute("xmlns").Value) {
    $Namespace = "{{{0}}}" -f $Namespace
 }'

Answer (score 0):

In Line 9 you are using the **XContainer.Descendants Method (XName)**.  This method returns a **IEnumerable Interface** which does not appear to support the .Value method, which is why I suspect it is returning null.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx

Just an amateur trying to help, hope this is on the right track.

Comment: Thanks JLA, that looks like some good reading. It looks like I'll be doing this more in my scripts so I don't think I can avoid getting in and understanding what it is I am looking at any longer.